# My Printers only print out blank pages

Tags: printing

I've just installed 12.10 - very good - all appears well, network connectivity is good - I can connect to devices on my network without issue.

I have two printers - a local HP officejet 4500 and a networked Ricoh Aficio MP 2050. When a test print is sent to the HP 4500 it prints a blank and then I get an out of paper error even though paper is present. When a test print is sent to the Ricoh printer it prints lots of blanks - this is a real pain as the networked printer is elsewhere in the building and by the time I get there its used almost a full pack of paper. The only way to stop the Ricoh printing blanks is to pull the plug and then deal with the paper jams.

I've tried both the drivers which ubuntu finds and a generic postscript driver on each printer without success.

I've previously used a variety of linux mint distros without this issue.

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: same issue here.

Comment: I'm getting the infinite blank papers with a Brother HL2140.  It feels like a practical joke!

Answer (score 0):

For the HP I downloaded HPLIP,after searching through HP's site, because I was having problems printing on my HP printer.

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html

It was fairly easy to set up and has instructions on the page.

I am unsure about the other one.

You could look at this page:

https://www.openprinting.org/printer/Ricoh/Ricoh-Aficio_MP_C2050

and see if the drivers work.